# What is wrong with this Google Elevation API URL?

Tags: python, google-maps, url, polyline, http-status-code-400

I am making an application using mainly Python to find the most fuel efficient route using primarily Google Maps data. I have been using the [Encoded Polyline Algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) to get elevation data, as well as a small [Python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polyline/) for the conversions. Normally, the conversion from LatLngs into polyline works fine. However, this URL returns a 400 error:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=enc:yf{{EreegNl{WqnW_pKl{gAzqHsuYb_Cedg@sln@r{n@vaIpcBnm]viUzrm@kd^aebA|n`@t_aAe{L}}BmzLynfAi}X~sa@ukh@~|WfwmBa}b@krlAnqc@q|CubJdxsAes`@ca_Bh`Rw}Ob_m@bivAy|k@vnDzq_@_zx@g`LxxkAkzu@mrhAvwl@v_jAipZol\\jb[ejfA~p[ndzAmrhAgm_@nkStrAj|BhjZwtj@uhl@bh@{zDxfq@l{z@qf^_igAjbt@e~FydLssQmpZlv~@jlVq|y@_{d@xk`@~cfAbyr@qsfAs}|@srAvk]kcEqf@x~j@n{Qi_q@_gY|khAptr@~o@grxA}`_A`u{@lgMolJhpl@qsj@mcUxaoAab_@eklAxj`@isDr`Gz`Fhra@xb`@{{T{zc@ihPbrvA{xBgmrBpl\\hxgB_yZc`gBsvIr`}At~FelzA`oElsBrzg@pmtAqaaAmlUvce@rhh@ndZy|X}~p@mos@yxRn{X`eeAr}Ywg|@y_ArlPgwCvfNwby@gaDnjzA}pEDieIcgVuiX{waA}yC~uTp|u@|saAjiSynv@}th@klq@`la@phu@srqAilHfqkAtax@qmmAcvp@npmA~no@y_YusTg_PaodAouIrdg@ttg@nqx@cwQipDt~`@wslAqtFc|AybVtmAo{Nv`s@qbQ_bUfy`A~il@{oMautAqyaAlhZfsl@fdf@xzEslcAsvn@xdo@`t{@iup@_{NdgdB_pa@k_Zp_h@||X}}t@idlA|az@irY_pGkbIrhC`puAgkI{eg@}mm@ej@xtyAzlq@yc_@{__A}t@q|Z_jNhlBd}IbrmAxFw{Cqu[vfLjmj@iflA_|j@jilAde`@rbPccg@{xvA~aU|yaAnjMshgAc`NlchAgzGdz@qc^itg@f}h@`he@zbn@{pJkudAuvH~xe@qp`AulGpi~Apm[cvQggShea@~ye@cxTqmnA}xa@|qd@gjg@i_Ahax@r`Kay_A`eOlwOw|hArte@zs|@}cl@y`T|``Aovi@qmXj`V}th@gvM|zw@fjk@|vf@xna@{ddAovoAb{U|wYcfb@hjLarYghS~j}@{jLoxLyjCbaVjvFy_`@hc`@w}k@gs@wv@puJ|k_@s~Kw`YoStcmBalGmgVag^}fWpq@d{Dfqe@c_FaqWnoZpgg@uaoAlsPdb_Aisd@dgA_f\\uqh@ecObxD~bq@do_Azui@cl^gzBdsV_hQvsGknW{_fAr`Mnvn@j{Fmmw@}gVx~hAoBo_cBjcFjd{Ayot@myi@vezA_wJmtHtf@cfgAzxVviw@t}Viad@uo^dyd@iu[}h~@nnOfqgAl`_Akx_@wvb@htAdj[_wLmqIxse@g~}@pfW~deAw}c@sv_BibIlzyAn`l@fpFq`y@kiY{f^ed[ha~Apuj@gyV~wR}`@}EtzJsjG{_`@em_@d|Hyw_A_dl@p`t@jwy@glXa`EdhmAm~p@qdkAnwmAxuw@mBsfVwg^ooe@fn\\vrr@ism@nc`@zaAyzK{sAwpm@brH{{XweNnedAuiGm`_AckPdfy@n}g@yuqAuiAo@wwN``Ue~UjvCjcVreo@hqA~lC}_^uxp@lpo@kga@o|[dv~@nl`@ylw@gfMd{eBwxBs{U~z\\jiOxzH}{DqsImblAac[`~rAg`@aclApym@|iZycYrvVffHheXqvHpaBlhGeq_@ilQnya@obW}waBbzQu{OsrAt~yAzrB`s@rr_@yxx@mhGvqAm~bArjCn`Z~vi@fvXy_s@ivFi`Lh~KhbaAe_[c{Jrou@zyFyrq@jrS{uIcl_@glMs|Lv~y@lyv@wrbAohk@dxr@otw@i_\\n|~@hqVwaz@~cCv`kAha\\liH_odAu}x@nvJlqr@`_OszB`eDs`Bb`Ps`w@v|FgzGkm`@t~Ixiu@dws@{bXicy@q`t@fik@kb@gnh@y_Drce@ple@kxj@ima@jc[|_lA`~Jckf@f|q@_{Tmko@pt]vuVkoTl~BjyZfdOopU_Hljp@cjU_o`AcfPirI|s@rdIshb@pkJxgs@|nu@eiCcumAsop@rxPbzn@tlPazC_m_@a_]
```

Using both the python module and `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath()`, the line has valid points in it (300 to be exact).

Any other line made like this works fine. **What makes this line in particular not work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum length of a URL is 2,083 characters, the posted URL is at least 2154 characters

sources:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum+length+of+URL
- [SO] [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

This has changed over time.  The maximum length in the documentation is now 8192 characters.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about that, but since none of my other queries even came close, I was not considering that as a problem.

Comment: Actually the URL length restriction in Google's documentation appears to be 8192 characters - manually testing the API confirms this.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro
However, there may be a smaller restriction imposed by browsers, libraries, proxies etc.

Comment: updated the answer to reflect the fact that it has changed over time.